# jquery, alert when trying to submit empty field in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm sure I must have missed something really obvious, but can't for the life of me see what it is.

I have the below javascript, that (in theory) looks at the form when I click submit, and tells me if I have left the 'RefNo' field blank (in the final form there will be various fields to check, so I have used class='required' to identify them all). But so far, when I click submit, nothing happens (except the form is submitted with the missing data).

I've tried various options that I have found on the internet, and this seemed the most promising.

If anyone can see what I have done wrong it would be really appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitForm()
        {
            $("#Form1").submit(function()
                {
                    $('.required input').each(function() 
                        {
                            if ($(this).val() == '') 
                                {   
                                    $(this).addClass('highlight');
                                }
                        }
                    );

                    if ($('.required input').hasClass('highlight')) 
                        {
                            alert("Please fill in a Ref Number and try again");
                            return false;
                        }
                }   
            );
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="POST" action="test9.php" name="Form1" ID="Form1">
        <input TYPE="text" ID="RefNo" NAME="RefNo" VALUE="" size="25px" class="required"></input>

        </br>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" Name="submit" id="submitButton" value="Report History" onClick='submitForm()'></input>
        </p>
    </form> 
</body>
```

Comment: html5 has a required attribute that will make using javascript irrelevant.

Comment: But you still need to know how to do it without that attribute for people who aren't using an HTML5 compliant browser.

Comment: @nathanhayfield No it will not, what about browsers that don't accept html5, and don't say "Well people shouldn't be using them browsers" it's users choice. You have to have a fallback for everyone.

Comment: Yes you do, otherwise it is inaccessible for users. Major companies like BBC and most government run businesses use IE7, seriously you need to go back and learn the basics.

Comment: Actually users don't always have a choice on what browser they use because of work/school rules and they may only have an older browser that does not support html5

Comment: on a side note the jquery submit function doesn't need you to use an onclick function on the input button to call it. it works on the form no matter how you submit it.

Comment: @user2406160 For IE7 users you simply redirect them to a 404 page that tells them to get a real browser and provides a link to Chrome...

Comment: Yes *cough cough* "All IE7 users, yes that's right you government run businesses, get a real browser before using this website!" I'm pretty sure that would go down well, kudos for your imagination my good sir, and I'm guessing you're not very bright so I think I should tell you, that was sarcasm.

Comment: wow - html5 'required' just made my life so much easier (most of what I do is internal to the company and so runs on Chrome). Although I appreciate the sentiment of knowing the basics, as most of my customers use IE in various forms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your selectors should be `$('input.required')`, not `$('.required input')`.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you should use Jquery validation plugin.

Ohterwise, this code should work :

-add a onsubmit="return submitForm()" in your Form tag

```
<form method="POST" action="test9.php" name="Form1" ID="Form1" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
```

-get rid of the onclick on the submit button

-and here is the submitForm function :

```
function submitForm() {
var valid = true;

$('input[class="required"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '') {   
        alert("One field is empty and try again");
        valid = false;
    }
});

return valid;
```

}

But I really recommend jquery.validate.js

Answer (score 0):

Your selector appears to be a bit off:

It should be `$('.required')`

The way you have it tries to select an input nested inside a Required class.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it on form submit, remove the submit input type from the button and just have it be a regular button.

With that in mind, your javascript should be:

```
<script>
    $('#submitButton').click(function () {
        $('input.required').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {   
                $(this).addClass('highlight');
            }
        });

        if ($('.highlight').length > 0) {
            alert("Please fill in a Ref Number and try again");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $('#Form1').submit();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Otherwise, the way that you're doing it, you would have to cancel the event until you run your check for missing data, and then submit the form anyway. This way keeps you from having to cancel the action, as older IE browsers do that differently than the other browsers, and even newer versions of IE. So it makes your code more readable.

Answer (score -1):

The selector should be either **$('input.required')** or **$('#RefNo')**.

**$('#RefNo')** is more faster since it uses native **getElementById** method.